# How to get the Topic icon/emoji from the icon_emoji_id?

Tags: c#, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

I am writing an ASP.NET Core web app where I want to display a list of the channels and groups with topics, showing the configured icons/profile photos for each.

The channels are fine and I can use:

```
await WT.Client.DownloadProfilePhotoAsync(t.Channel, photoOutputStream, false, false);
```

to download the image for serving.

What I'm struggling with are the - what looks like - custom emojis for the forum topics.

I have tried the following, where t is an instance of my model class for passing to the controller:

```
var forums = await WT.Client.Channels_GetForumTopics((Channel)subChat.Value);
if (forums != null)
{
    
    t.Topics = forums;
    foreach (ForumTopic forum in forums.topics)
    {
        if (forum.icon_emoji_id != 0)
        {
            var result = await WT.Client.Messages_GetCustomEmojiDocuments(subChat.Value.ID);
            System.Console.WriteLine(result[0].ID);//debug breakpoint
        }
    }
}
else
{
    t.Topics = null;
}
```

The problem seems to be that Messages_GetCustomEmojiDocuments returns DocumentBase[] and not Document[] thus I can't get any further details about the topic emoji as described [here](https://corefork.telegram.org/method/messages.getCustomEmojiDocuments).

Is this approach correct? Can you advise a way I can achieve what I need to do please?

Answer (score 0):

well `WTelegramClient` is heavily tight to `pattern-matching`, almost every API in telegram has some inheritance associated with its objects.
in your case, when you get an `DocumentBase` it can either be `TL.DocumentEmpty` or `TL.Document` ( also included in the documents)
so you can write:

```cs
var result = await client.Messages_GetCustomEmojiDocuments(1);

foreach (var documentBase in result)
{
    if (documentBase is Document document)
    {
        // document variable now contains every information you need
    }
   
}
```

you can put an `else` statement after the `i`f and hard cast your `documentBase` to `(DocumentEmpty)` since there is no other possibilities or you can play it safe and do this:

```cs
switch (documentBase)
{
    case Document doc:
        break;
    case DocumentEmpty empty:
        break;
}
```

either way you have to access the inner data using `pattern-matching`

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you. I was able to get the custom emoji document and thus the relevant tgs file for each topic.

Comment: The confusion came as the required default topic (id=1) cannot have a custom emoji and was always of type DocumentEmpty. I'm still having problems getting this default chat icon (#), or any other topic icon where it's not a custom emoji so if you can help with that also it would be much appreciated. Should I create a new question for this?

Comment: @AngusMack could you explain your problem further? using `doc` and `empty` you should be able to parse all of the emojis, what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: When icon_emoji_id is 0 (usually for the default first topic of the forum with topic id=1) it means it's using the default icon, which is the # sign. icon_emoji_id can also be 0 when using a static icon e.g. the ? In a speech bubble icon. It's this use case I am struggling to deal with i.e. how do I find and download or reference these static icons in this case so I can display them in my web client? Hope that's clear? Let me know if you need more information. Thank you.